# will_paginate nested object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I have a model that has the following association:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :gallery, dependent: :destroy
has_many :gallery_images, :through => :gallery, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I would like to paginate just the gallery_images as opposed to the tournament itself but as I am getting the gallery_images as a nested attribute I'm not sure how to do this using will_paginate

**Controller**

```
def galleries
  @tournaments = Tournament.all
  #tried this
  @gallery_images = @tournaments.gallery_images.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
end
```

**View**

```
                 <% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
                    <div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                          <ul class="team-gallery">
                            <% t.gallery_images.each do |g| %>
                              <li>
                                <%= link_to image_tag(g.photo.url(:gallery_large)), g.photo.url(:gallery_large), class: 'clb-photo' %> 
                              </li>
                            <% end %>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
```

How can I paginate just the t.gallery_images?

Comment: Post your `TournamentsController` with method where the `pagination` is done.

Comment: its alreay there but ive updated with what i have tried

Comment: Ok. Now change this line `<% t.gallery_images.each do |g| %>` to `<% @gallery_images.each do |g| %>`

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465949/how-to-use-will-paginate-with-a-nested-resource-in-rails?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure this is working code?

```
@gallery_images = @tournaments.gallery_images.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
```

You are calling `gallery_images`, what appears to be an instance method, on an ActiveRecord collection, which is essentially an array. That won't work.

I suspect you want to loop over the tournaments and call paginate on the images of each tournament.

```
<% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
  <%= will_paginate t.gallery_images.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9) %>
<% end %>
```

You can create an instance method on the `Tournament` model to save you from writing all that each time you want to paginate tournament images.

```
class Tournament
  def paginated_images(page, per_page = 9)
    gallery_images.paginate(page: page, per_page: per_page)
  end
end
```

Then you can do this in your view:

```
<% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
  <% images = t.paginated_images(params[:page]) %>
  <% images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag image %>
  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate images %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller define a helper method `paginate_images`

```
helper_method :paginate_images

def paginate_images tournament
  @images = tournament.gallery_images.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
end
```

In your view

```
 <% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
        <div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="team-gallery">
                <% paginate_images(t) %>
                <% @images.each do |g| %>
                      <li>
                        <%= link_to image_tag(g.photo.url(:gallery_large)), g.photo.url(:gallery_large), class: 'clb-photo' %> 
                      </li>
                 <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: unfortunately thats still paginating the Tournament object and not just targeting the gallery_images

Answer (score 0):

Having tried both answers, wasnt working as expected, still getting undefined methods, though both answers helped a lot and the solution so far is below..

It works to the point that the gallery_images are paginated, but ill be making some tweaks, what i have so far is kind of ugyy in the view but will create a helper method to change that

```
<% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
  <div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul class="team-gallery">
        <% images = t.gallery_images.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9).each do |g| %>
         <li>
           <%= link_to image_tag(g.photo.url(:gallery_large)), g.photo.url(:gallery_large), class: 'clb-photo' %> 
         </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
       <%= will_paginate images %>
     </div>
```